# Create arrays based on a different array

Tags: matlab

```
% create variable x with array of all necessary values
x=linspace(0.1,13,50);

for i=x
    % create equation to determine y
    y=(sqrt(2.*i)*4*i.^3)/(4.*i+7.^(i/10));
    %create equation to determine z
    z=log10(2.*i+5)+(4.*i+exp(i))/(2./3+4.*i.^2);
end
```

Using Matlab and im trying to use values from my x array to create two arrays, y and z, im pretty new to matlab and im struggling, thanks.

Comment: i got it figured out

Comment: Avoid using `i` as a variable name. It shadow the built-in `i` function that return the imaginary unit. Also in your example, you don't need to use the element-wise operators (`.^`, `.*`,`./`) if `i` is a scalar. The best option is to use the element-wise operators directly with `x`, for example `y = sqrt(2*x)./x`

Answer (score 1):

The problem in you code is that you did not use `for` loop properly. You can run through the index of `x`, then assign `x(i)` to a new variable `k` in each iteration, i.e.,

```
x=linspace(0.1,13,50);

for k = 1:length(x)
    i = x(k);
    % create equation to determine y
    y(k) =(sqrt(2.*i)*4*i.^3)/(4.*i+7.^(i/10));
    %create equation to determine z
    z(k) =log10(2.*i+5)+(4.*i+exp(i))/(2./3+4.*i.^2);
end
```

Since MATLAB is able to vectorize the operations, so you are recommended to do it like below to speed up (`for` loop in MATLAB is expensive)

```
x = linspace(0.1,13,50);
y = (sqrt(2*x).*4.*x.^3)./(4*x+7^(x/10));
z = log10(2*x+5)+(4*x+exp(x))./(2/3 + 4*x.^2);
```

**Remarks**: you should be careful about the difference between `.*` and `*`, or `./` and `/`, where `*` and `/` are not element-wise operations.

Comment: Note that it is possible to use for `i = x` and will loop through objects. This feature only works with arrays (so the initialization with `linspace()` is OK). If you have a vector (size ?x1) it will use the entire row as the only iterating object. Though object-looping is quite nifty, it is unintuitive if you learned loop from low-level languages as C (or worse). For clarity, it is better to use the "normal" index looping as @ThomasIsCoding suggested =)

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

you can initialize `y` and `z` into empty arrays and just append the corresponding result at the end:

```
% create variable x with array of all necessary values
x=linspace(0.1,13,50);

y=[];
z=[];

for i=x
    % create equation to determine y
    y(end+1)=(sqrt(2.*i)*4*i.^3)/(4.*i+7.^(i/10));
    %create equation to determine z
    z(end+1)=log10(2.*i+5)+(4.*i+exp(i))/(2./3+4.*i.^2);
end
```

This approach can prove to be poor in terms of efficiency, since the size of `y` and `z` changes dynamically.

Method 2:

If you still want to use a `for` loop, it is better to preallocate memory for `y` and `z` and iterate the indices of `x`, something like:

```
% create variable x with array of all necessary values
x=linspace(0.1,13,50);

% Memory allocation
y = zeros(1, length(x));
z = zeros(1, length(x));

for i = 1 : length(x)
    % create equation to determine y
    y(i)=(sqrt(2.*x(i)*4*x(i).^3)/(4.*x(i)+7.^(x(i)/10));

    %create equation to determine z
    z(i)=log10(2.*x(i)+5)+(4.*x(i)+exp(x(i)))/(2./3+4.*x(i).^2);
end
```

Method 3 (preferred one):

It is generally more efficient to vectorize your implementations. In your case you could use something like:

```
x = linspace(0.1,13,50);
y = (sqrt(2.*x)*4*.*x.^3) ./ (4*x + 7.^(x./10));
z = log10(2*x+5) + (4*x + exp(x)) ./ (2/3 + 4*x.^2);
```

Comment: You should allocated memory beforehand (e.g. with `NaN()`) for variables `y` and `z` for efficiency. Matlab stores arrays contiguously in the RAM and; thus, relocates them every time it outgrows the curent position